# Seaborn `relplot` x-axis label rotation :: AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have created multiple using seabron `relplot` with x-axis being the date. I tried number of things as below to rotate the axis so those dates should be readable

```
g = sns.relplot(x="deliveryDate", y = "value",
            data = delivery_data_plt, kind = "line",  col="productTitle", 
                legend = False,  markers = True, col_wrap = 4)
#g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
#ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),  rotation=45, fontsize=7)
#ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation = 45)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

Could you please suggest/guide me something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JohanC `AttributeError: Use the `.axes` attribute when facet variables are assigned.``

Comment: Oh, you have multiple subplots:  `for ax in g.axes.flat:  ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)`